# Migrating on-prem Excel to Sharepoint and update Formula links

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel

We have 1000s of files to migrate from on-prem to Sharepoint and many are Excel with formula links.

Is there an easy way to update the formula links after uploading?
*powershell?*

Has anyone used some of the products out there and know if they are any good?

Just looking for some advice from someone who has already done this to point me in the right direction.

Thanks,
Roger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to these similer issues(third-party tools that may be suitable for you):

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/migrate-excel-files-with-a-lot-of-links-to-sharepoint-online/m-p/121062

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/tool-to-auto-fix-broken-excel-links-after-migration-to/m-p/290940